# Prove that if $f(z)$ is analytic at infinity, then $\lim_{z \to \infty}{ f'(z)}= 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I don't really know how can i prove that. I know a function $f(z)$ is analytic at $z=\infty$ means $f(\frac{1}{\xi})$ is analytic at $\xi = 0$.

In particular:

$$\lim_{z \to \infty}{f(z)} = \lim_{\xi \to 0}{f(\frac{1}{\xi})} = f(\infty)$$

Always exists and is finite. Also, I think it follows that:

$$\lim_{z \to \infty}{f'(z)}=\lim_{\xi \to 0}{f'(\frac{1}{\xi})}$$

But I do not know how to continue.

Comment: Let $g(\xi) = f(1/\xi)$. Consider the relation between $g'(\xi)$ and $f'(1/\xi)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer You could be a little more specific?

Comment: You want to show that $\lim\limits_{\xi \to 0} f'(1/\xi) = 0$. Express $f'(1/\xi)$ in terms of $g'(\xi)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding a suggestion by [Daniel Fischer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1558264/prove-that-if-fz-is-analytic-at-infinity-then-lim-z-to-infty-fz#comment3172829_1558264):

Let $g(\xi) = f(1/\xi)$. Then $g'(\xi)=-f'(1/\xi)/\xi^2$. Since $g$ is holomorphic at $0$, the derivative $g'$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $0$: $|g'|\le M$. It follows that 
$$|f'(1/\xi)|\le M|\xi|^2 $$
or, to put it another way, 
$$|f'(z)|\le M/|z|^2 $$
when $|z|$ is sufficiently large.